# How do I directly control the http body (big size) when using hyper?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio, hyper

Currently, we are switching the API gateway engine made in c to tokio, hyper, rustls of rust.

While analyzing the echo server example provided by hyper_rustls (tokio_rustls), there is a part that I do not understand and ask for help.
(I'm struggling with not many examples to refer to)

https://github.com/rustls/hyper-rustls/blob/main/examples/server.rs

Here's the flow I was thinking of:
When a POST request with a large body size is received, all http bodies are read → After reading up to content-length, the future code passed to make_service_fn is executed (echo operation in the example).

However, as soon as the request is received, the code passed to make_service_fn is executed and a response is sent to the client, and the poll_read function of the tokio::io::AsyncRead trait is executed many times. This has been run.

Q: When exactly does the make_fn_service code run, and is this something I can control?

**Q: When using hyper, it seems to store the body accumulating in memory. Therefore, if the body size is very large, I would like to work with such as downloading it to a separate file. Is there a way to directly control every time the body comes?**

- Can I use the hyper::body::HttpBody trait?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

About Q1:

```
let service = make_service_fn(|_| async { Ok::<_, io::Error>(service_fn(echo)) });
```

You call `make_fn_service` to convert an async function into something that can be passed to `serve()`. It gets an argument of type `&AddrStream` and can do all kind of fancy stuff such as filtering and throttling, but if you don't need any of these, just call `service_fn` with your async function.

Then your function, `echo` in the example, will be called once per client request.

About Q2:

The body is not accumulated in memory:

```
*response.body_mut() = req.into_body();
```

But these are of type `Body`, that implements `Stream<Item=Result<Bytes>>`, being these `Bytes` the chunks of the body request/response.

And by asigning a `Stream` to another `Stream` a very big ping should be painlessly streamed through the `echo` function, one chunk at a time.

If you want to manage the data yourself you can poll the stream (`StreamExt::next()`) and handle each piece of body individually. Just do not call `Body::to_bytes()` or `Body::aggregate()`.

About using the `HttpBody` trait:

Sure you can use it directly, but it is non trivial. I think it is usually implemented so that you can get for example a JSON object directly from the request, or an XML or a urlencoded map or whatever your Content-Type dictates, without doing an intermediate byte array and a parse.

But as you can probably guess, processing huge XML/JSON payloads in async mode is not easy. And if you really need that you can probably make it easier just driving the byte chunks of a plain `Body`.

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick reply, it really helped a lot! But I'm still a beginner and many things don't make sense right away.

In fact, the reason I thought it was accumulated in memory was because an over max size error occurred when sending data close to 1G (though it was a misunderstanding).

Comment: `*response.body_mut() = req.into_body();`

I understood this code as an operation to empty the data in the read buf after putting it into the write buf (so it is not accumulating in memory). Once do the above logic of the echo function, is it correct that hyper internally asign buffers to other buffers until the body ends (I don't know what the principle is)?

Comment: And...If you know how to use StreamExt::next() in hyper service, can you give me a simple example..?

Comment: I'm no expert about `hyper`, but that is my understaning, the buffers will be assigned one by one, from one stream to the other. About a simple example the standard idiom would be `let body = req.body_mut(); while let Some(chunk) = body.next().await { let bytes = chunk?.into_bytes(); /*...*/ }` or something like that.